# Copy workbook without copying all sheets?

Tags: excel, vba, copy

I have a very large excel file (~50Mb) with around 100 sheets. Since it is so big, I need an "Export" macro that makes a smaller copy of it, so I am able to email it. This copy, also needs some of the macros that are in the "master" file.
The way I do this now, is by first making a copy of the whole file, and then deleting the sheets that the user doesn't need. This takes of course very long, and it's a waste of time, since usually the user only needs 10-15 of those sheets. My system before was to create a new, blank workbook and then copy the needed sheets, but I have code in modules and in "ThisWorkbook" that won't be copied into the new file like this.

Does anybody know a better way than copying the whole file? I appreciate your help-

/David

Comment: Create a template that includes the Thisworkbook code and the Modules you want to include in the copy.  Create the new Workbook from the template, and copy the required sheets into that

Comment: Hey Chris, thanks so much for your reply. Sorry to ask so much but how do I do that? I don't really understand.
.
EDIT: I understand that to save as a template is just a matter of defining the right extension, but how do I give the instruction in VBA to save this or that modules?

Comment: Create the template manually (once) - in Excel when you save as, select xlst as the doc type.  Then in VBA when you create the new book, [specify the template](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbooks.add)

Comment: You can create a secondary workbook with the VBA macros you want (which is what the comments above are about), however in this workbook, you can have linked data (eg. `='Path\'[workbook.xlsm]worksheet!A1`) to the worksheets you are interested in. When you want to e-mail you just need to set up a small macro to copy and paste as values through each worksheet to lock the data.